# Using Box-Muller Method to Generate Gaussian Random Numbers in Python

Tags: python, random, gaussian

Right now, I am using the Box-Muller method to generate 10 24 Gaussian random numbers in python. I am supposed to plot the power spectrum, and see a Gaussian curve. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def fast_fourier_transform(y):
    '''Return the fast Fourier transform of y.'''
    Y = np.fft.fft(y)
    f = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y),1.0/1024)
    return f,Y

    rlist=[]

    for i in range((2**10)/2):
        mu=0
        sigma=1

    u = np.random.random()
    v = np.random.random()

    z1 = np.sqrt(-2.0 * np.log(u)) * np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * v)
    z2 = np.sqrt(-2.0 * np.log(u)) * np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * v)

    x1 = mu + z1 * sigma
    x2 = mu + z2 * sigma
    rlist.append(x1)
    rlist.append(x2)
    print u, v, x1, x2
f,Y=fast_fourier_transform(rlist)
plt.plot(f,Y)

plt.show()
```

However, when I plot this, I don't get a Gaussian distribution. My question is this: why am I not getting a Gaussian distribution in my Gaussian-generated white noise power spectrum? Am I plotting something wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the Gaussian curve, you want a histogram rather than a power spectrum.  The power spectrum of independent random variables is uniform (flat).  The term "white noise" is itself a big hint - white light is comprised of equal amounts of light at all frequencies.